# Binomial Expansion for n < 1

Tags: binomial-theorem

Write Down the First 3 terms of $\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{x}{8}}$

*My First step :* After Evaluation, I got $$\Bigl(\frac{1}{8}x + 1\Bigl)^\frac{1}{3}$$
but, $${{\frac{1}{3}} \choose {r} } = \text{undefined}$$
How am I supposed to do this or am I missing something crucial ?

Comment: Look up [binomial series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Yes ! The first values of ${{\frac{1}{3}} \choose {r} } $ are $\left\{1,\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{9},\frac{5}{81},-\frac{10}{243}\right\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{x}{8}}=1+\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1!}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x}{8}\bigg)^1+\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{3}\times(\frac{1}{3}-1)}{2!}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x}{8}\bigg)^2+\cdots=1+\frac{x}{24}-\frac{x^2}{576}+\cdots$$